# How to avoid a hierarchy in ruby classes?

Tags: ruby, class, functional-programming

I am processing 2-dimensional shapes in ruby. I have a Point class with x and y attribute, and a Line class which has two end points. Later in the process chain, I often want to identify and process vertical lines slightly differently from horizontal lines, even though both can occur in the same set of Lines. I have mix-ins to do the processing, but often I find the method has something like

```
if l.vertical?
  l.do_something_with_y_coordinate
elsif l.horizontal?
  l.do_something_with_x_coordinate
end
```

I see this pattern quite frequently and I do not like the repetition. I could try to avoid it by identifying instances of Line that are vertical and creating a VerticalLine class, and a HorizontalLine class, but that feels more like .Net than ruby and does not reduce the duplication, just encapsulates it.

Another way might be to have a direction method that returns :x or :y and then a method to "do_something_with direction".

Does anybody else have any suggestions about how to refactor?

Answer (score 4):

It's not "more like .Net", it's more like proper object-oriented encapsulation. If you learned that via .Net, that's fine, but it's a very general approach that dates back decades before .Net or Ruby ever existed.

There's three ways to tackle this problem:

1. Use an `if` to split behaviour.
2. Use subclasses to implement the specific behaviour.
3. Generalize your code so it doesn't matter if it's vertical or horizontal, the same math is applied in both cases.

In the third case imagine having vector(s) or a matrix which describes the geometry you're manipulating. For example, `[0, 1]` could represent a vertical line going up, or `[-1, 0]` a line going to the left depending on your coordinate system. Each iteration you just add that to your base point. The very idea of horizontal or vertical melts away.

Comment: It's likely that #3 is the correct answer here. It seems strange to me to have different kinds of lines. #3 also gets rid of the awkward question whether a line at a 45° degree angle is vertical or horizontal :-D

Answer (score 1):

In the concrete case I see three suggestions:

1.) Define accessors which map to `x` and `y` depending on the two cases:

```
def s=(value)
  if horizontal
    x = value
  else 
    y = value
  end
end 

def t=(value)
  if horizontal
    y = value
  else 
    x = value
  end
end
```

With this you can delegate to the "right" field dynamically.

2.) Convert your horizontal cases into vertical ones by rotating, then performing the operation and then rotating it back.

3.) Using another representation that doesn't use `x` and `y` such as polar coordinates where your differentiates vanishes.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, adding new accessors seems to be the best way- I will try it and see. That is what I meant by having a main direction of the line - returning either the x or y coordinate, but I wasn't very clear. I started using parallel and perpendicular, but your s and t is neater and clearer! Actually the lines were originally sourced by using a Hough-like transformation, using polar coordinates, but now I want to join them up into shapes so your options 2 and 3 don't really seem to help much.

Comment: Actually my 'parallel 'and 'perpendicular' were also poor choices as names for the directions and hopelessly confusing given that I am trying to identify and combine lines that are all either parallel or perpendicular. Having Neutral terms makes it clearer.